# Mysql Reading from the stream has failed

Tags: c#, mysql

I have tiny exe's,  I am developing with c# the size is max 100kb - 500kb.

A 3rd party application opens these exes for me, when my application is opened, it reads some data from MySql database, processes it, then writes the result back to MySql database.

they are very normally useful on servers, but sometimes I get this error, it's not clear when, sometimes after 1 week, sometimes twice a day

> Authentication to host '192.168.1.200' for user 'root' using method
> 'mysql_native_password' failed with message: Reading from the stream
> has failed.

this error does not happen on every computer, it does not happen all the time, I never encounter it when compiling on my own computer

I tried a lot of things so far I couldn't come to a conclusion by looking at some suggestions on this site

I added or removed MySql password is not a solution , ports defined to firewall and antiviruses

`private string connectionstring = "Server={0};Database={1};port={2};username={3};password={4};CharSet=latin1;SslMode=None";`

[image: I am working with this version of MySql]

Comment: This error has been reported frequently at the MySQL bug reporting site: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76597 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=75917 https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=86056. Some of those reports suggest workarounds. Other developers have resolved it by switching to https://www.nuget.org/packages/MySqlConnector/.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger thank you so much for replying. I hope they fix it quickly, I'll go to that library like everyone else.

Comment: @BradleyGrainger these bug dates are so old 2017 2019 vs why it hasn't been resolved until now

Comment: I don't know why they haven't been fixed yet, but I do know there are many unresolved bugs in MySql.Data dating back 5+ years: https://mysqlconnector.net/tutorials/migrating-from-connector-net/#fixed-bugs

Comment: @yhackup I've just fallen into this mess and I get the definite feel that it's all being dismissed as stale connections even when it's obviously not.  (I'm looking at a stack trace that shows the problem during an open--which occurred when a background task fired while the main one had just thrown an exception because the connection disappeared while awaiting the result of a query.)

Comment: @yhackup. I have the same problem. Have you solved it yet?

Comment: @LeoGarsia  Unfortunately, Oracle did not offer a solution. I loop until successful connection is established